# matplotlib, ticks are overlapped when hspace=0

Tags: python, matplotlib

When pushing two plots together, I'd like to have the the ticks set to 'inout' and have it properly displayed over both the charts, but the 2nd chart is overlapping it.

[image: chart-problem-image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.01, 5.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t, s1)
plt.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False, direction='inout', length=6)

ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
plt.plot(t, s2)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

plt.show()
```

We can adjust the hspace and see that they're there, but just getting covered.

[image: ticks-visible-image]

I've tried changing the z-order, but that didn't work.

```py
plt.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False, direction='inout', length=6, zorder=100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can create `ax2` before `ax1`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.01, 5.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)

ax2 = plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t, s2)

ax1 = plt.subplot(211, sharex=ax2)
plt.plot(t, s1)
plt.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False, direction='inout', length=6)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [zorder demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html):

> Drawing is done per Axes at a time. If you have overlapping Axes, all elements of the second Axes are drawn on top of the first Axes, irrespective of their relative zorder.

So that explains why setting the zorder didn't help.  Another option might be to set the second axes' facecolor to 'none', which makes it transparent:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.01, 5.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
s2 = np.exp(-t)

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t, s1)
plt.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False, direction='inout', length=6)

ax2 = plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
ax2.set_facecolor('none')
plt.plot(t, s2)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]